# Shopping card price rule NOT overriding catalog price rule

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules

I'm having issues with the catalog price rules not applying the discount correctly and i have figured out that the shopping card rule does what i need to.

Unfortunately even though i have the Shopping cart rule at priority 0 and to Discard subsequent rules and the other at say 10 priority the catalog rule is also applied once added to the cart.

Say we have a product with 10% discount at catalog price rules and another 10% discount at shopping cart rule.

I only want the shopping cart rule to be applied to the product.

Thank you in advance

Comment: both are completely different, `priority 1` Shopping cart rule will override `priority 1` Shopping cart rule. same apply for `catalog price rules`, please tell what actually you want achieve so that community may help....

Comment: i'm having rounding issues when using catalog discounts. So i need to use shopping cart rules and do a "custom" display price. Can we continue in chat to elaborate ?

Comment: `rounding issue` means are you telling  it will display in `decimals` ?

Comment: already posted in the forum here
https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/Round-price-before-apply-any-catalog-price-rules-to-it/m-p/54274#U54274

Only way i got it to "work" was through using shopping cart rules and not catalog rules.